# Windows form ElementHost hosting a wpf menu usercontrol that opens windows forms childs on the windows forms host

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, xaml, user-controls

i know this may look a Little confusing, but i have an application built in Windows forms, that has a menu and almost 20 options in a treeview that opens Windows forms child on the main form, but it looks awful, so i wanted to build a usercontrol in wpf that has the options and storyboards, but my problem is that i cant find a way to open the child forms on the main menu when i click the corresponding option in the wpf usercontrol

do someone knows is this is possible?

```
        ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
        UserControl2 uc1 = new UserControl2();
        host.Child = uc1;
        host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(host);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did it with this logic

```
        public FormParent parent { get; set; }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromDependencyObject(button);
        var host = (System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost)System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromChildHandle(source.Handle);
        var form = (System.Windows.Forms.Form)host.TopLevelControl;
        FormChild newMDIChild = new FormChild();
        newMDIChild.MdiParent = form;
        newMDIChild.Show();
```